# Which MWS API should I use to get inbound and fulfillable quantity of a product?

Tags: amazon-mws

I would like to get 'inbound quantity', 'fulfillable quantity' and session of each product. Any one please help me to find out which MWS API call I should use for getting this data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Option #1:**

Use the [Fulfillment Inventory API](https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html/185-8681654-1411166?ie=UTF8&group=fba&section=inventory&version=latest) which is documented [here](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/fba_inventory/index.html).

Use the [ListInventorySupply](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/fba_inventory/FBAInventory_ListInventorySupply.html) operation, which returns an `InventorySupplyList` containing [InventorySupply](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/fba_inventory/FBAInventory_Datatypes.html#InventorySupply) elements.

`InventorySupply` contains [InventorySupplyDetail](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/fba_inventory/FBAInventory_Datatypes.html#InventorySupplyDetail) elements, which in turn contain `SupplyType` elements, which can be of type `Instock`, `Inbound`, or `Transfer`.

**Option #2:**

Use the [Reports API](https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html?ie=UTF8&section=reports&group=bde) which is documented [here](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/index.html).

The [ReportType enumeration](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_ReportType.html) includes [FBA Reports](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_ReportType.html#ReportTypeCategories__FBAReports), which has an **FBA Inventory Reports** section containing valid enumeration values for different reports.

**Instock** and **Inbound** values are available in the `_GET_AFN_INVENTORY_DATA_` or `_GET_FBA_MYI_ALL_INVENTORY_DATA_` report types.